# Strange behaviour debugging a document with AUCTeX-GNUEmacs in math mode

Tags: miktex, emacs, auctex, debugging

When I try to compile this document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
A simple fraction with an error $\frac{a}{b$
\end{document}
```

I obviously get an error because there is a missing `}` in the fraction and then the minibuffer says:

```
LaTeX errors in `*c:/Program Files/emacs-23.3/bin/debug_error output*'. Use C-c ` to display.
```

So I press <kbd>C-c `</kbd> and then the windows splits in half and I have two buffers: the lower is the expected TeX Help buffer and the upper is a strange empty buffer called MiKTeX 2.8 in Nroff mode. I also noticed that this happens when there are errors in math commands or something like that.

How to prevent the MiKTeX 2.8 buffer appear? It would be nice to have a workaround.

EDIT: After reading the documentation I found this:

> <kbd>C-c ‘</kbd> should always stay in the current window, also when it finds a
>   new file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoking `latex` with `-file-line-error-style` will fix most of these problems.  Your example, however, it will not.  You can read the discussion on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885853/emacs-latexmk-function-throws-me-into-an-empty-buffer/7903668#7903668).  One work around mentioned there is to change what file is the default to be the master file.  That way when `latex` can't say what file the error was in, then AUCTeX will assume it was in the file you are editing.  I suspect this will be right over 90% of the time, and extremely confusing the rest. `:-)`

Adding the following advice to your `.emacs` file should do the trick.

```lisp
(defadvice TeX-parse-reset (after make-master-file-default () activate)
  (push (concat (substring (buffer-name) 1 (- (length (buffer-name)) 8))
                "." TeX-default-extension) TeX-error-file)
  (push nil TeX-error-offset))
```

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug in AUCTeX, see [this post](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.auctex.bugs/1675) for a brief discussion.  It looks like some of the behavior is fixed in the development version, but I have not had the chance to test it on my machine.

Comment: Yes, some kinds of errors like that open a strange buffer. On my machine (with Aquamacs) it's empty and named `TeX Live`.